# SSRS Single report parameter used to set dataset query parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I'm a bit of an SSRS noob and would appreciate some assistance with report parameters.

I have a SQL query similar to the following:

```
SELECT [abc],[xyz],[etc]
FROM [database].[dbo].[db_view]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Normally this will result in two report parameters being created, [Start Date] and [End Date]. However the default date picker scenario becomes tedious for users when running reports several times for a prior periods and can often select incorrect start and end dates.

The preferred approach is to provide users with parameters like [Year] and [Month] and have these defaulted to current values, e.g.: Year:[2014] Month:[March], and use these selections to set the SQL query parameters accordingly, i.e. the latter selection would be used to set @StartDate='2014/03/01' and @EndDate='2014/03/31'

I'm not sure how parameters can be set as described above; any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without parameter expressions (requires SQL Server 2012 data source)

1. In SSRS, ensure separate parameters are created: `@Year`, `@Month`, `@StartDate`, `@EndDate`
2. Use [DATEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) to build the start and end dates in your dataset

   ```
   SELECT [abc],[xyz],[etc]
   FROM [database].[dbo].[db_view]
   WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @StartDate)
                AND DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @EndDate)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I ended up doing the following: Removed StartDate and EndDate parameters, added Year and Month parameters with default values and set available values, configured StartDate and EndDate parameters on DataSet to reference Year and Month using DateSerial function. Tested it out and works as required :-)

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS, add 2 hidden Parameters, Start and End date.  Set the defaults of these to an expression.  Build out your date strings using the values from your visible year/month parameters, and use CDATE() to convert them to a date type.  Use these 2 hidden parameters in your SQL query(s).

For the year/month parameters, simply add those, navigate to their "Available values" property tab, and either hard-code in your collection of months & years, or wire up a dataset to provide the available values to the parameter.